# converting audio from mp4 to wav and croping in the process using python

Tags: python, audio, ffmpeg, mp4, wav

I am looking for a package where I can use to convert the audio file from `mp4` to `wav` simultaneously while also cropping the file using python.

I have seen some posts about using `ffmpeg` to do the conversion but I dont seem to be able to run `ffmpeg` within python, and when converted to `wav` the files become around 10 times bigger which is kind of a storage issue.

Does anyone have any suggestions except for pipelining it?

Comment: So the actual problem is that you can't get `ffmpeg` to run in your python code?

Comment: what I found out that ffmpeg can do is that it converts the file and writes it somewhere. can it also convert it to wav and write some portion of it to some array for further processing?@llogan

Comment: It can output to a pipe or named pipe. See [FFmpeg Protocols](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html) for other options. Why do you not want to use a pipe?

Comment: @llogan it is not a good idea to use pipes with such large files. pipes do have limited capacity and files Im handling easily go up to hundreds of megabytes.

Comment: Don't rely on the capacity: make sure the reading app consumes the data fast enough that the writing is not blocked.